# How to use useHistory() hook in Class Component Type Script

Tags: typescript, react-router

Hello I am trying to use

```
this.history.push({
                    pathname: `/search-results`,
                    search: `${job}$${location}`
                  })
```

In my class component that is using type script .
However it is giving me back an error of Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Banner'.  TS2339

I can see other examples of functional component, you can do `const history = useHistory();` and use history.push from hook.

How can I do the same thing in class component?

Answer (score 5):

Hooks are not designed to work with class based components.

However, react-router has other methods to support class based components such as the [`withRouter` higher order component](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/withRouter).

That said, use functional components and hooks if you can. They are the React standard going forward.

Comment: I tried to follow the syntax with you link you sent me and I am currently getting an error of "Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'"

Comment: Nevermind you have to define const { history } = this.props as any, i really hate TS omg